# Python, OpenGL, and GTK.

Tags: python, opengl, gtk, pygtk, pyopengl

I want a GTK GUI with two OpenGL areas that will have different scenes drawn onto them.  Does anyone know of an example of code that does this?

[This blog post](http://modarnis.com/Articles/gtk_gl_python.html) offers an full working example but when I try to add a second OpenGL drawing area, it seems that OpenGL draws both scenes to the same widget.  This, of course, is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any number of those:

```
    widget = self.gtkBuilder.get_object('OpenGLDrawAreaOpenGLFuBar')
    self.OpenGLGizmo['fubar'] = OPenGLFuBar()
    glarea = gtk.gtkgl.DrawingArea( glconfig=self.glconfig,
                                    share_list=None,
                                    render_type=gtk.gdkgl.RGBA_TYPE)
    self.OpenGLWidget['fubar'] = glarea
    glarea.set_size_request(333, 333)
    red = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glarea.connect_after('realize', self.OpenGLGizmo['fubar'].realize_main)
    glarea.connect('configure_event', self.OpenGLGizmo['fubar'].configure_event)
    glarea.connect('expose_event', self.OpenGLGizmo['fubar'].expose_event)
    glarea.set_flags(gtk.HAS_FOCUS | gtk.CAN_FOCUS)
    glarea.add_events(gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS_MASK)
    glarea.connect('key_press_event', self.OpenGLGizmo['fubar'].key_callback)
    widget.add(glarea)
    glarea.show()
    glarea.realize()
    glarea.grab_focus()
```